# RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while converting py to exe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

I created a program and was trying to convert the `py` to `exe`. For which I firstly installed `pyinstaller` by
`pip install pyinstaller` and then I went to the directory where the program is and opened terminal in that directory.

The command which I used to convert the `py` to `exe` was `pyinstaller --onefile main.py`.

`main.py` was my file name and I didn't use `-w` because I need console and my program doesn't have any GUI.

I'm getting **RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded** Error. The `dist` and `build` directory are created but `dist` doesn't have anything inside.

The program which I'm converting is available [here](https://github.com/abhi7585/Hangman-Version-2).

Comment: please share build output as well

Comment: ```build``` consist of one folder named ```main``` which has two files inside in it one is ```base_library.zip``` and another is ```main.exe.manifest```.

Comment: oh sorry, i meant the error you are getting.

Comment: As I mentioned in the post  RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded. This is the error I'm getting. In the terminal.

Comment: im able to generate .exe, can u tell ur python version? and pyinstaller version?

Comment: This is a bug in PyInstaller we're working to fix. See https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/4406 for more details.

Comment: @GauriShankarBadola I'm using the latest version of conda environment python and the latest pyinstaller version. What code did you use?

Comment: `Python 3.7.0` and `pyinstaller 3.6`

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug in PyInstaller we (The PyInstaller devs) are working to fix. See https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/4406 for more details and to watch the progress of the fix.